Deeplinking to an android app with two same URL with different params
I am using compose deep link navigation.
I have two composable's
    composable(
        route = StatusRouteNavigation.STATUS_LANDING,
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "${BuildConfig.DOMAIN_URL}us/en/manage/status.html"
            }
        )
    )

    composable(
        route = StatusRouteNavigation.DETAILS,
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "${BuildConfig.DOMAIN_URL}us/en/manage/status.html?page=de&no={number}&on={date}"
            }
        )
    )

The problem here is that. When I click the url in android device it always navigates to the details page.
Are there any option to handle deeplinking in this scenario?

Please include the intent-filter snippet, the value of BuildConfig.DOMAIN_URL, and the testing links used for reproducing the issue. I tested the provided code, and it worked correctly for me. The problem might be related to the details I mentioned above. Read further about How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example here.

The issue you're experiencing is due to the deep link patterns matching criteria. The deep link for the DETAILS route is more specific and likely matching the URL patterns better than the STATUS_LANDING route. When multiple deep links could match a given URL, the most specific match wins.
To resolve this, you can refine the patterns to ensure they match correctly and do not overlap. Here's a possible solution to differentiate them:

Modify the deep link for the STATUS_LANDING route to be more specific and ensure it doesn't match the DETAILS pattern.
Ensure the DETAILS pattern only matches when the page, number, and date parameters are present.

For example:
composable(
    route = StatusRouteNavigation.STATUS_LANDING,
    deepLinks = listOf(
        navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "${BuildConfig.DOMAIN_URL}us/en/manage/status.html"
        }
    )
)

composable(
    route = StatusRouteNavigation.DETAILS,
    deepLinks = listOf(
        navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "${BuildConfig.DOMAIN_URL}us/en/manage/status.html\\?page=de&no={number}&on={date}"
        }
    )
)

Notice the escaped question mark (\\?) in the DETAILS pattern. This helps to ensure that the parameters are correctly matched.
By making the patterns more distinct, the navigation component can correctly identify which route to navigate to based on the URL. Try testing this updated configuration to see if it resolves the issue.

This is not working. Now the first deeplink is only working

Kuldeep Gupta, Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should have already seen this in the banner while posting your answer, but please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post is not permitted on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related Help on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!
